# Deploying NodeJS/Express site with FTP to PHP-native server

Tags: node.js, express

I am a novice within web development, and am currently trying to deploy my first website to a domain & web hotel that I've bought with some friends for a music label that we're starting.

I've built the website using NodeJS, ExpressJS, and TailwindCSS. It's a very simple site with just 4-5 mostly static pages. No user functionality, no database connections etc. Our domain provider allows for FTP upload as well as SSH connection.

The problem that I have, as far as I understand, is that the remote server is not Node-compatible as-is, rather, it provides PHP its standard service.
I managed to connect to the server using SSH and install Node etc. using the SSH terminal, but still, when I push my website using FTP, I only get 404 errors. Could it be possible that the remote server is completely Node-incompatible, even if I manage to install Node with SSH?

I think that maybe I need to make some more changes to my code in order for it to be deployable, but I haven't been able to figure out which ones. I added "start": "node app.js" to my package.json file, but it still does not seem like the online version of my website "recognizes" where my app begins. Maybe the .htaccess file?

I hope some of you can help me! Please let me know if you'd like to see some of the code that I've written.

Thank you!

Comment: It can be many things. It could be a web serwer like NGiNX or apache that proxy+pass all traffic to the php. If it shared server that can have a custom configuration prepared by the hosting company etc.

Comment: @quentino Thanks for your answer. I dug a bit deeper and found that the server runs Apache 2.4, and NodeJS/NPM is ticked off in the services, so should be fine. 
I just get 404 errors for every route that I try to go to in the browser. It's like the entry point of my app, the app.js file, hasn't been declared properly or something. Does this sound reasonable, or am I on the wrong track? Thank you